# Relay light on but not providing power

Tags: python, pi-4, relay

Hi I am trying to create an automated watering system using a submersible pump, raspberry pi 4 and 2 channel relay.

The setup I had before worked until I added a usbc power supply(5v) and after that the relay light goes on but it doesnt click and no power is provided to the pump.

Before I was using a simple battery pack to power the pump. I have tried 3 relays and tested the pump and usb C power supply directly and they both work but for some reason the pump isn't getting power when it's all connected.

I put a volt meter up to the relay when it is switched on and there is no reading.

I also went back and tried the battery pack again but no help.

For reference this is the usbc adapter I use. [usbc-adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Youmile-Type-C-Adapter-Connector-Converter/dp/B09MRJX9MB?pd_rd_w=OOh3F&content-id=amzn1.sym.e9c30756-181a-4068-ac3a-74afd7f110a2&pf_rd_p=e9c30756-181a-4068-ac3a-74afd7f110a2&pf_rd_r=P4Z0FT3PFWYYYT09MS58&pd_rd_wg=7DCh7&pd_rd_r=18d03d50-9079-480d-a88b-c72506690873&pd_rd_i=B09MRJX9MB&ref_=pd_bap_d_grid_rp_0_1_i&th=1)

This is the code I use for activating the relay.
**relay-test.py**

```
#Import all neccessary features to code.
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#This means we will refer to the GPIO pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#This sets up the GPIO 18 pin as an output pin
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

while (True):    
    #This Turns Relay Off. Brings Voltage to Max GPIO can output ~3.3V
    GPIO.output(18, 1)
    print("OFF")
    sleep(1)
    #Turns Relay On. Brings Voltage to Min GPIO can output ~0V.
    GPIO.output(18, 0)
    print("ON")
    sleep(3)
```

Below is a fritzing diagram of the system.(The battery pack is meant to represent the usb type c power supply)

[image: A fritzing diagram of the system]

Comment: If you want help provide details of components and a circuit diagram (not a meaningless Fritzing layout).

Comment: does the pump run when you remove the two red wires from the relay contacts and touch the two red wires together?

Comment: `I put a volt meter up to the relay when it is switched on and there is no reading` ... that's because the contacts are closed and you are measuring the voltage drop between two points of a short piece of wire ... instead, measure the power supply voltage when the contacts are closed